# ESLint producing different output when run with npm run-script

Tags: npm, eslint

When I lint my code with `eslint scripts/**/*.js` I see two linting errors:

```
» eslint scripts/**/*.js
/Users/user/dev/scripts/application.js
  3:8  error  "React" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

/Users/user/dev/scripts/components/Header.js
  24:2  error  Unnecessary semicolon  no-extra-semi

✖ 2 problem (2 error, 0 warnings)
```

That's fine. When I put that command into `"scripts"` in my `package.json` then I only get one error.

```
// package.json
// ...
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint scripts/**/*.js"
}
// ...


» npm run lint
/Users/david.tuite/dev/ui/scripts/components/Header.js
  24:2  error  Unnecessary semicolon  no-extra-semi

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

What's happening to the other linting error?

**edit**
I'm starting to suspect this is a globbing problem. The missing linting error is in a file which isn't in a subdirectory of `scripts`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Globs work differently in the `package.json` file.

The trick is to wrap the path matchers in single quotes to have them expanded at the shell level before they're passed to eslint.

```
// package.json
// ...
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint 'scripts/**/*.js'"
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like David's answer solved the problem he was encountering. However, I had an identical symptom to the problem described.

In my case the problem was that npm was using the node_modules in the project directory which had a different version of the plugin than the global npm folder had.

Running eslint from command line was using the global version. Reconciling those versions resolved the issue in my case.